# UniqueEntity validation in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a database table as below:

```
 payment_method
 --------------
 pk id
 fk payer_id
    payment_method
    bank_name
```

Here payer_id can have null value. I have a UniqueEntity as below

```
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields={"paymentMethod","payer","bank"},
*     errorPath="payer",
*     message="This payment source is already in use.",
*     groups={"persist"}
* )
```

This validation works fine if payer_id is not null. It does not work for following cases:

```
 id    payer_id    bank_name  payment_method
 1                 US Bank      credit card
 2                 US Bank      credit card
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ignoreNull=false`. If set to false, only one null value is allowed - if a second entity also has a null value, validation would fail.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#ignorenull

Comment: having `ignoreNull=true` allows for multiple entities to be null. `ignoreNull=false` allows a single value to be null. so how does `ignoreNull=false` solve the issue of the validation failing on payer_id=null (a single value is null)? Both ignoreNull=true and false should allow this validatation, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set ignoreNull to true as option in the UniqueEntity constraint, yours would look like this then:

```
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields={"paymentMethod","payer","bank"},
*     errorPath="payer",
*     message="This payment source is already in use.",
*     groups={"persist"},
*     ignoreNull=true
* )
```

However this option is the default value and I doubt that you changed it, so the error probably is that you have set some fields to `unique=true` at a `@ORM\Column( ..., unique=true)`.

This will not be validated by validation constraints, and frankly almost impossible to do for any SQL database to allow a unique constraint with multiple NULL values.

You would have to remove the `unique=true` from your `@ORM\Column` definition.