# Symfony2 - UniqueEntity not working ignoreNull with two fields

Tags: php, validation, symfony

Symfony2 - UniqueEntity not working ignoreNull with to fields

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Service.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"host", "port"},
 *     errorPath="port",
 *     message="This port is already in use on that host."
 * )
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Host")
     */
    public $host;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = true)
     */
    public $port;
}
```

I try to add port with null value, it throw "This port is already in use on that host." error.

I want to ignore validation when port is null.

Answer (score 3):

Check this link for solution.
[UniqueEntity validation in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231204/uniqueentity-validation-in-symfony-2)

**ignoreNull¶**

**type**: boolean default: true

If this option is set to true, then the constraint will allow multiple entities to have a null value for a field without failing validation. If set to false, only one null value is allowed - if a second entity also has a null value, validation would fail.

Comment: I want not add host but port=null multiple entries, its not allowing

Comment: More information in this link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#ignorenull